# Without using case when how to sum the values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to tune up the query to make it run faster. Currently, I am using case when to sum the value **How can we tweak it to solve the performance issue** .

> Note table contains 120 column with 10 million records.

Current query is **:**

```
select week ,nullif(Sum(Convert(Numeric(18,2),Amt)),0) [Amt] , 
nullif((case when (Desc<>'FF')then Sum(Convert(Numeric(18,2),Amt)) else 0 end ),0) [Amt2] 
from Table1 group by Week,Desc
```

**Table1:**

```
╔════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║  Week  ║ Desc  ║  Amt   ║
╠════════╬═══════╬════════╬
║      1 ║  FF   ║  25.00 ║
║      1 ║  ss   ║  55.00 ║
║      2 ║  ss   ║  78.00 ║
║      2 ║  FF   ║  99.00 ║
║      3 ║  ss   ║  54.00 ║
║      4 ║  FF   ║  58.00 ║
║      5 ║  FF   ║  55.00 ║ 
║      5 ║  ss   ║  55.00 ║ 
║      1 ║  ss   ║  77.00 ║
╚════════╩═══════╩════════╝


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] ([Client_Billing_Id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                            [Weekday] [varchar](10) NULL,
                            [Description] [varchar](1500) NULL,
                            [NetAmount] [varchar](100) NULL )

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Description] ON [dbo].[Table] ( [Description] ASC )
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: As you're converting your data before summing, what are you storing it as? This is likely the reason for your slow performance; poor data choices. Can you share your table's DDL please? Ensure you include any Indexes on the table as well.

Comment: yes converting it before summing up, sorting based on the week , index created for the Desc column

Comment: I know you're converting it before hand, that's what I said you're doing. My question was *"what are you storing it as?"* To repeat myself again: *"Can you share your table's DDL please? Ensure you include any Indexes on the table as well."*

Comment: It was varchar, I have placed the ddl of my table below :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
 [Client_Billing_Id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Weekday] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [Description] [varchar](1500) NULL,
 [NetAmount] [varchar](100) NULL
 
) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Description] ON [dbo].[Table]
(
 [Description] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your column `NetAmount`. You're storing a numeric value as a string, thus the SQL server is having an awful time of summing the values.

Also, you have no index on the column `Weekday` meaning that the server has the scan the entire table before it can group anything.

Next, your column `Description`. Why is it a `varchar(1500)`? From you're post your **clearly** only storing 2 characters, so what are the other 1498 characters for...?

I would do the following

1. Change your `NetAmount` column to a `decimal` (possibly `(18,2)` based on your query).
2. Change the `Description` column to a `char(2)` as you only ever use 2 characters. The space for the other 1498 characters is a complete waste
3. Change the Weekday to an `int`. it's clearly not a varchar and this means ordering will be correct. Weekday shouldn't be in the order `1, 10, 12, 13...19, 2, 20, 21,...3, 30, 31, 4, 5, 6, 7...`
4. Add an index on `[Weekday]` and `[Description]` and `INCLUDE` the column `NetAmount`.

This results in something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table] ALTER COLUMN NetAmount decimal(18,2);
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table] ALTER COLUMN [Description] char(2);
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table] ALTER COLUMN [Weekday] int;
CREATE INDEX Week_Desc_IX ON dbo.[Table] ([Weekday] ASC, [Description] ASC) INCLUDE ([NetAmount]);
```

Then, your query simply becomes:

```
SELECT [WeekDay],
       CASE [Description] WHEN 'FF' THEN [Description] ELSE 'SS' END AS [Description],
       NULLIF(SUM(NetAmount),0) AS [Amt],
       NULLIF(SUM(CASE [Description] WHEN 'FF' THEN Amt END),0) AS [Amt2] 
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY [Weekday],
         CASE [Description] WHEN 'FF' THEN [Description] ELSE 'SS' END;
```

This *should* perform significantly better.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful. For Description column Sometime we get description more than 500 char so we made it as 1500. My question is if we keep on adding index to a table (preferred columns),  Will it cause any performance issue while inserting data to the table ?

Comment: Yes, but your table only has 4 columns, so there's not really many more Indexes you can add.